# Workflows with Dynamic nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm trying to configure a Jenkins's Workflow (Trough workflow-plugin) that can work with dynamic node names in an environment in which slaves are managed automatically.

Unfortunately it turns out that `node()` does not support regex, nor the common wildcard `*`:

```
node('node-*') {
}
```

There is any way to make `node()` work with dynamic slave names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK This is sort of a RTFM situation:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md

> The parameter may be a slave name, or a single label, or even a label 
>   expression such as:
>
> node('unix && 64bit') {
>       // as before }

So I can simply use a label to identify nodes.